# Yiimp pool reject all blocks

Tags: pool, mining, stratum

i have setup my YIIMP pool but seems that all blocks are rejected, i think is blocknotify problem

```
14:54:03: BTCRUBLE 213314 - diff 1.592820338 job e to 1/1/1 clients, hash 165.101/114.019 in 0.1 ms
14:54:05: *** REJECTED :( BTC RUBLE block 213314 1 txs
2018-02-02 14:54:05: REJECTED BTCRUBLE block 213314
14:54:23: BTC RUBLE 213314 not reporting
14:54:24: BTCRUBLE 213315 - diff 1.592820338 job f to 1/1/1 clients, hash 157.281/114.019 in 0.1 ms
14:54:25: *** REJECTED :( BTC RUBLE block 213315 1 txs
2018-02-02 14:54:25: REJECTED BTCRUBLE block 213315
```

My conf file of wallet is like this:

```
rpcuser=btcrublerpc
rpcpassword=mypassword
rpcport=4921
rpcthreads=8
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
# onlynet=ipv4
maxconnections=12
daemon=1
gen=0
```

When i add this blocknotify part i get error blocknotify not found:

```
alertnotify=echo %s | mail -s "BTC RUBLE alert!" myemail@gmail.com
blocknotify=blocknotify 94.177.204.50:3433 1425 %s
```

Can someone help please? i can pay to get it working.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in your blocknotify call did you put /var/stratum in front of blocknotify example : blocknotify=/var/stratum/blocknotify 94.177.204.50:3433 1425 %s

Answer (score 0):

Rejected blocks have nothing to do with 'blocknotify' that is mere a notification whenever a block has been found. It has no impact, whatsoever on mining.

The problem you are facing your blocks being rejected could be related to Yiiimp coin's admin misconfiguration per se or coin's conf file is not properly configured.

You need to thoroughly check BTCRUBLE's Settings and Daemon tabs in Yiimp coin's admin.

Apparently coin's conf seems fine perhaps you need to add this param

```
server=1
```